Sign RS256 JWT with Yubikey PIV is incorrect
I want to sign my JWT with Yubikey PIV and want to use RS256 alg.
I found yubico-piv-tool, found how to make a sign and wrote bash script. The script creates sign (I check it with openssl) correctly, but, when I am trying to convert sign to JWT sign, something happenes and it break the signature. I guess that there is a mistake in signature conversion, but can't find it.
Could somebody help me?
There is a script, which I wrote
#!/bin/bash

# step 1 - generate a new key pair on a YubiKey
alg="RSA2048"
sha="SHA256"

yubico-piv-tool -a generate -s 9c -A ${alg} -o pub.pem
# step 2 - generate data to be signed

#jo iss=issuer aud=audience > payload.json
now=$(date +%s | cut -b1-13)
echo '{"htm": "GET","htu": "https://host/token","iat": '"${now}"'}' > payload.json
echo '{"typ": "dpop+jwt", "alg": "RS256"}' > header.json
# base64-encode header and payload
basenc --base64url header.json | tr -d '\n=' > header.b64
basenc --base64url payload.json | tr -d '\n=' > payload.b64
echo -n . > dot
cat header.b64 dot payload.b64 > datatosign

# step 3 - sign using yubikey
yubico-piv-tool -a verify-pin --sign -s 9c -H ${sha} -A ${alg} -i datatosign -o signature.der

# step 4 - verify

# verify using openssl
openssl dgst -${sha} -verify pub.pem -signature signature.der datatosign
# convert openssl signature
#cat signature.der | openssl asn1parse -inform der | egrep -o '[A-F0-9]{64}' | xxd -r -p | basenc --base64url | tr -d '\n=' > signature.b64
cat signature.der | base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr -- '+/' '-_' > signature.b64
# construct jwt
cat datatosign dot signature.b64 > token.jwt
# verify using step
cat token.jwt | step crypto jwt verify --key pub.pem --iss issuer --aud audience --alg RS256
# verify using jwt.io
echo "Open the following URL in your browser:"
echo "https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=$(cat token.jwt)&publicKey=$(jq -sRr @uri pub.pem)"

